# Modala creates website from nested JSONs

Tags: javascript, json, framework

My question pertains to the style in which I've written this function. Is there anything else I can do, to create a better resolution for user when they create a template from their JSON modal? This is PipesJS + Modala. I get a sufficient amount of clones to keep it going. And no one says anything about issues. This is the best setup I can do right now. Here is the JS for creating a Modal in Modala:

```
 // modala(jsonObj,rootNode)
function modala (value, tempTag, repeat, replace, root)
{
    if (tempTag instanceof String)
    {
        tempTag = document.getElementById(tempTag);
    }
    if (root === undefined)
        root = tempTag;
    if (tempTag == undefined)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (value == undefined)
    {
        console.error("value of reference incorrect");
        return;
    }
    var temp = document.createElement((value["tagname"]));
    console.log(value);
    Object.entries(value).forEach((nest) => {
        const [k, v] = nest;
        if (v instanceof Object)
            modala(v, temp, repeat, root);
        else if (!Number(k) && k.toLowerCase() != "tagname" && k.toLowerCase() != "textcontent" && k.toLowerCase() != "innerhtml" && k.toLowerCase() != "innertext")
        {
            console.log(k + " " + v);
            temp.setAttribute(k,v);
        }
        else if (!Number(k) && k.toLowerCase() != "tagname" && k.toLowerCase() == "textcontent" || k.toLowerCase() == "innerhtml" || k.toLowerCase() == "innertext")
        {
            (k.toLowerCase() == "textcontent") ? temp.textContent = v : (k.toLowerCase() == "innerhtml") ? temp.innerHTML = v : temp.innerText = v;
        }
    });
    if (replace == true)
        tempTag.innerHTML = "";
    
    tempTag.appendChild(temp);
}
```

```
You can see the whole setup here at [github.com/wise-penny/pipes][1] and you can see an example at [g0d.me/pipes][2] (no SSL, sorry)


  [1]: https://github.com/wise-penny/pipes
  [2]: http://g0d.me/pipes
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.